# Accessing objc static object's properties in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I get the following compile error in Swift 2 using Xcode 7.1
The CloudConfig object is an objective C singleton class returning static

CloudConfig.h

```
   @interface CloudConfig : NSObject<NSCoding, NSMutableCopying>
   {


   }
   @property  (nonatomic, retain) NSString* brandAccountName;
```

CloudConfig.mm

```
   + (id)sharedInstance {
         static CloudConfig *sharedInstance = nil;
      @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedInstance == nil)
         sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
        }
     return sharedInstance;
    }


   var cfg = CloudConfig.sharedInstance()
   cfg.brandAccountName = "somestring"
```

Cannot assign to property: 'cfg' is immutable

This works in Objective C but fails in Swift 2.  How can I access the properties of the objc singleton.

Thanks

Comment: Show the declaration of the CloudConfig object type and its `sharedInstance` method, please.

Comment: Thanks, i've updated the code

Comment: So `sharedInstance` is not publicly declared in the interface file??

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `sharedInstance` returns an `id` and not a CloudConfig. Either fix the Objective-C declaration or cast in Swift.

Comment: Thanks, the compiler message could have been clearer